# Send a simulated keypress from ZLE script to terminal

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

Is it possible to simulate a keypress from withing zle function?

```
test (){
BUFFER="sudo $BUFFER"
CURSOR=$#BUFFER
<??send right-arrow keypress??>
}
zle -N test
bindkey "^f" test
```

I feel it would be a solution to my visual irk, where when I play with buffer and cursor position, I have remnant cursor on the original position of the cursor. I think that if I would be able to send right-arrow keypress to the terminal from within the test function, that it would remove it

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that this is a glitch of your terminal emulator. I just tested your code with `zsh` versions 5.0.6 and 5.2 on three different terminal emulators (`urxvt` 9.22, `xterm` 324 and `termite` v11) both with and without `zsh-syntax-highlighting` (which you seem to use). No constellation resulted in the artefact your screenshot shows. Which terminal emulator are you using? Is your `zsh-syntax-highlighting` up-to-date? Does the issue persist, if you try it in a plain zsh session? That is without configuration files; you can start such a session with `zsh -f`.

Comment: @Adaephon its more a glitch of the frameworks as I found out by testing..   I tested it in several temrminals as well, It happened in all I tested. But switching to oh-my-zsh fixed it, but both prezto and zsh-zim had it. I use default settings on all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works with xdotool package

```
sudo_ (){
    BUFFER="sudo $BUFFER"
    CURSOR=$#BUFFER
    xdotool key 0xff53
}
zle -N sudo_
bindkey "^f" sudo_
```